# Wordpress: Critical error on "user-new.php" when adding new user

Tags: wordpress

Funny thing is: The user is created.
But i get a "Critical error" on the page "user-new.php"

I can't get a log of the error.
Might be a plugin error (obviously) but anyone else experiencing this ?

Comment: Do you get any details about what the critical error was?

Comment: No. No errors what so ever

Comment: There must be an error logged by Wordpress. Have you checked the server logs? Also, if the error is happening at user-new.php, have you tried debugging it and finding out which line is throwing the error?